# Kivy error on pc 64 bit installing windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, kivy

i m getting an error while installing kivy on windows 64 python.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgKiH.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqeF2.png)

Comment: My python is 64 bit and pip is up to date but i am getting this error multiple times

Comment: Isn't pkg-config a Linux utility?

Comment: So i have install python 3.7 and its working